# cannot run Selenium tests on some browsers

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, opera, mink

i have tests made with Mink using Selenium 2 driver. everything is working OK under Windows 7 with Firefox, Chrome and IE and Ubuntu 12.10 with Firefox. the problems are:

1. when i try to run test on Opera (Windows 7) it launches but it cannot find any element on the page - the test fails.
2. when i try to run test on Chrome (Ubuntu 12.10) using chromedriver - the system returns an error "An unknows server side error occured while processing the command".
3. when i try to run test on Opera (Ubuntu 12.10) - the system returns an error "No response in timely fashion".

what am i doing wrong? how can i make work Opera in Windows and Opera and Chrome in Ubuntu?

p.s. i use system as Selenium Grid 2

Comment: add some time delay before try locating the element

Comment: yes, i tried to add some additional delay - no result. the test itself is correct - because it run successfully in Firefox (and Chrome and IE under Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows it work:

```
java -jar "c:\selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar" -forcedBrowserMode "*googlechrome c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

May be for u:

```
java -jar "c:\selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar" -forcedBrowserMode "*opera c:\Program Files\pathToOpera.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a matter of Operative System as well.
I am developing on a Windows machine and my colleagues are working on Mac. 
They had just included the chrome driver for mac, so tests didnt´t work on my computer.
I had to do this:

```
 if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",   "src/test/resources/selenium_drivers/chromedriver.exe");
         } else if ((OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0)) {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/selenium_drivers/chromedriver");
        }
```

Two different driversa that you can find at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html